# Create a SQLite database with Monotouch - permission denied

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a Sqlite database using Monotouch 3.0.3.4. Everything works fine on the iPhone simulator, but I get the following error on the test iPhone:

DataLayer.CreateDatabase Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/private/var/mobile/Applications/4B4944BB-EC37-4B0C-980C-1A9B60DACB44/TestApp.app/myDatabase.db3" is denied.

Here is the code I am using:

```
// creates database and tables if they do not exist.
public void CreateDatabase ()
{
string sql = string.Empty;
string dbFileName = "myDatabase.db3";
try {
          if (!File.Exists (dbFileName)) {

    // create database
    SqliteConnection.CreateFile (dbFileName);  //This is where the error occurs
    Console.WriteLine ("CreateDatabase: Database created."); 
            ... 

    }  
      catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine ("CreateDatabase Exception: " + ex.ToString ());
    }

    ...
```

I have also tried specifing the personal folder, but that has no effect. What do I need to do to make sure permissions are correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Monotouch 3.0.3.4

That's likely MonoDevelop 3.0.3.4. See **About MonoDevelop** to get the MonoTouch version.

> "/private/var/mobile/Applications/4B4944BB-EC37-4B0C-980C-1A9B60DACB44/TestApp.app/myDatabase.db3"

On devices the applications are signed, so their content can't change (without breaking the signature). As such you're **not** allowed to change things in the `.app` directory.

You should create (or copy) the database in the `Documents` directory and then open the database as read-write.

See the [linked article](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_the_File_System) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, the linked article gave me the info to get the database working. Thanks so much!

Comment: Great :) Please take the time to mark the question as answered (checkmark below the vote count) so other people searching for a similar question can quickly see there's a solution for them.